# SourceForge Wiki: how to add permanent links to sources in git repo

Tags: git, sourceforge, gitweb

I began a [Wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/jdcf/wiki/Home/) for a [sourceforge project](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jdcf/). In the home page I've put some links to code samples in the git tree. I commit often then the links becomes obsolete.

How can I put http links to latest on master branch?

Here is an example of link: `https://sourceforge.net/p/jdcf/code/ci/414b9c83de3a5a9f34303c4bb888b715ff6bbecb/tree/src-demo_01/org/dcf/demo/consumer/Component.java`

`/414b9c83de3a5a9f34303c4bb888b715ff6bbecb/` is the version I suppose, I wish to replace it by `LATEST`. How do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `HEAD` [seems to work](http://sourceforge.net/p/jdcf/code/ci/HEAD/tree/src-demo_01/org/dcf/demo/consumer/Component.java):

```
http://sourceforge.net/p/jdcf/code/ci/HEAD/tree/src-demo_01/org/dcf/demo/consumer/Component.java
```

This link should give the latest file without breaking.